# Disable a product in catalog_product_save_before event

Tags: product

I'm trying to disable a product inside the catalog_product_save_before event.

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
//$product->save();
```

I've also tried this, but I'm thinking this won't work because the product hasn't been added to the database yet.

```
$storeId = 0;
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

How can I disable the product?

Comment: Can you add your config and observer code. Also is this code executing from the admin or frontend?

Comment: Ah I have got it working now after shifting some code around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for all store view i think this is the dirty way to achieve this

```
<?php
    $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
    {
        $_storeId[] = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($_storeId);$i++)
    {
        $product_id=1;
        $storeid=$_storeId[$i];
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have tried that code with both catalog_product_save_before and catalog_product_save_after, changing "$product_id=1;" to "$product_id=$product->getId();", but the product still gets added with an Enabled status.

Comment: Oh I have shifted some other code around and it's working now, thanks a lot!